# Floating action button(FAB) is not showing in Angular2 nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I followed this [github post](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-floatingactionbutton) to do Floating Action Button in Listview.

So I have added this below two plugins in my applications:

**NativeScript 2.x**

```
tns plugin add nativescript-floatingactionbutton@^2.2.7
```

**NativeScript 3+**

```
tns plugin add nativescript-floatingactionbutton
```

I have added the Floating Action Button(FAB) inside this below html file:

**Edited:**

**html page:**

```
<StackLayout class="parent">

 <GridLayout rows="*, auto">

 <ListView row="0" rowSpan="2" [items]="notiAlertList" class="listview" height="180" *ngIf="notificationVisible">

    <ng-template let-item="item">

      <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="3*, auto">

        <StackLayout row="0" col="0">
          <Label [text]="item.name" class="item-name"></Label>
          <Label [text]="item.category" class="item-culture"></Label>
          <Label [text]="item.description" class="item-comments"></Label>

        </StackLayout>

        <Label [text]="item.time" class="item-time" row="0" col="1"></Label>


      </GridLayout>

    </ng-template>


  </ListView>

  <FAB:fab tap="fabTap" row="1" icon="res://three_dots" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" class="fab-button" />

</GridLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

**ts file:**

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";


  public constructor(private router: Router) {


 // registerElement("Fab", () => require("nativescript-floatingactionbutton").Fab);// If I add this line application getting crash when coming onto this page.


  }
```

**css file:**

```
.fab-button {
    height: 70;
    width: 70; 
    margin: 15;
    background-color: #ff4081; 
    vertical-align: bottom; 
    border-inline-end : right;
}
```

I'm unable to see the Floating Action Button.I don't know where I did wrong, please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 issues. What is your css for `fab-button`, iOS requires a height/width for the View component to render. Also your layout has a few things that can be cleaned up, which can improve performance and you depending where you want the FAB you need to change a few things. If you want to float the FAB over the listview, you should wrap the listview in a grid with 2 rows, put the listview on row 0 with a `rowSpan=2` and then the FAB on row 1 and align it with css (horizontal-alignment & vertical-alignment). Hope that helps.

```
<FAB #createEventFab row="1" col="0" (tap)="goToCreateEvent($event)" icon="res://ic_add_white" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" class="create-event-fab-button"></FAB>
```

Also finish the `registerElement` like so:

```
import { Fab } from "nativescript-floatingactionbutton";
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement("Fab", () => Fab);
```

Comment: hi brad martinm, please check my edited post. I tried what you have suggested.but still not able to see that floating button in android.

Comment: `<GridLayout rows="*, auto">` and `ListView needs `row="0" rowSpan="2"` that will get closer to what you need.

Comment: anyother suggestion.now also not able to see that floating button

Comment: Did you edit the FAB in the UI piece? I thought before you were using angular, and now you have a namespace on the view component like it's plain NativeScript xml markup? You don't need the namespace with angular html markup in NS

Comment: `import { Fab } from "nativescript-floatingactionbutton";` this import is not supported : cannot find module issue came. Where to add that registerElement?

Comment: app.component.ts